# Why would a company with a market cap over $100 million choose to be a non-limited, general partnership?

Tags: united-states, liability, partnership

Why would such a significantly profitable company choose to have unlimited liability? What benefits would still be afforded by the non-limited, general partnership structure? United States especially.

Comment: This depends on the type of business, what is it?

Comment: Private equity, finance, etc. are the relevant types I believe.

Comment: I can imagine reasons, but don't know enough to give a good answer at this point without more facts. The only company that comes to mind right off that operates that way is Lloyds of London.